Find the 1st business day and last business day of the previous month based on a date
I have a use case like this in Python: Find the 1st business day and last business day of the previous month based on a date. For example if date is 2024-06-10
first_business_day = '2024-05-01'
last_business_day = '2024-05-31'

I have tried like below
run_date = '2024-06-10'
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.strptime(run_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
previous_month_first_business_day = (d - timedelta(days=d.day)).replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
previous_month_last_business_day = (d - timedelta(days=d.day)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Result:
previous_month_first_business_day = '2024-05-01'
previous_month_last_business_day = '2024-05-31'

This is working fine for month of May, but when I want the same result for June, then using the above I am getting:
previous_month_first_business_day = '2024-06-01' # This should be '2024-06-03'
previous_month_last_business_day = '2024-06-30' # This should be '2024-06-29'

What should I do to achieve the right result?

You specifically replaced the day of the month by the first, without anything related to what a business day would be, so you get the first of the month as expected.

How are first and last business day defined, in your case? Does this consider bank / national holidays? Do the workers work weekends?

"This should be '2024-06-29' " - But the 29th is a Saturday. Are Saturdays business days in this system?

What research have you done? Does this help? First Business Date of Month Python

@wjandrea has it if you can use Pandas! especially the pandas USFederalHolidayCalendar collection may be all you need to skip holiday dates

Take a look at the builtin calendar instead of just datetime
import calendar
import datetime

def month_start_end_work(date_src, fmt_date="%Y-%m-%d"):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_src, fmt_date)

    # roll around January -> December
    month = 12 if dt.month == 1 else (dt.month - 1)
    year = dt.year if month != 12 else (dt.year - 1)

    # discover last day of last month
    for day in (31, 30, 29, 28):  # handle Feb cases
        try:  # already the correct year for leap
            month_start = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
        except ValueError:  # day is out of range for month
            continue  # month has fewer days (always decreases)
        if month_start == calendar.SATURDAY:
            day -= 1
        elif month_start == calendar.SUNDAY:
            day -= 2
        break  # last day name to be used
    else:  # did not solve and break
        raise RuntimeError("BUG: impossible code path reached")
    day_last = (year, month, day)  # TODO may want to make a datetime.datetime
    
    # discover first day of last month
    day = 1  # all months begin at 1
    month_start = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
    if month_start == calendar.SATURDAY:
        day += 2
    elif month_start == calendar.SUNDAY:
        day += 1
    day_first = (year, month, day)

    return day_first, day_last

>>> month_start_end_work("2024-06-10")
((2024, 5, 1), (2024, 5, 31))
>>> month_start_end_work("2024-07-10")
((2024, 6, 3), (2024, 6, 28))
>>> month_start_end_work("2022-01-01")
((2021, 12, 1), (2021, 12, 31))

If you have special days you know are days off (probably 6-12 annually), collect them into a list and just keep decrementing/incrementing for exact matches

This counts holidays as business days, doesn't have a convenient spot to add a check for holidays, and the functionality it does have (checking for weekdays only) is unnecessarily long and complicated.

indeed, though holidays are always a sticky topic.. holidays as you suggest is a great choice along with Pandas' timeseries (suggested by SO link in comments) .. but due to region and work specifics, my wholehearted suggestion is for companies to publish an (internal) API pair for a multi-year window block of holidays by-region and again for all known time company time, perhaps as a static JSON response, to augment or override public data at run or build time

given some source of extra holiday data, users can coerce it to a set of tuples to compare against and increment or decrement their day on

You were on the right track with getting the first and last day of the previous month. The next step is to increment/decrement as long as those days are weekends, which you can check with their weekday() method: the week starts at 0 with Monday, and ends at 6 with Sunday. Once you've ensured that the day isn't a weekend with weekday(), you have to ensure that it's also not a holiday, using a library like holidays. For example, to check for US holidays:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import holidays

def previous_month_business_day_endpoints(d, h=holidays.US()):
    d = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    end = d - timedelta(days=d.day)
    start = end.replace(day=1)
    while start.weekday() > 4 or start in h:
        start += timedelta(days=1)
    while end.weekday() > 4 or end in h:
        end -= timedelta(days=1)
    return start, end

This will correctly handle inputs like '2024-2-1', as the first weekday of January 2024 happens to fall on New Year's.
